# Mathematica installation: cannot find Microsoft Visual Studio \VC\bin on visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to transfer some **C++ lib and files** to visual studio main folders. the tutorial is just explained for visual studio 2012 and I think the path are changed a bit for 2019.

This is the main path that I am trying to find on 2019:
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11\VC\lib** ,  **..\VC\include** , **..\VC\bin** 
I need to transfer three files to these locations. what is the exact location equivalent to these locations (I found some relevant folders but need to make sure). This is my sub-folder structure
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC** and then three sub folder

1. 1- Auxilary  2- Redist 3- Tools

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer form this link but I believe lib files must be place in lib folder:

[mathematica installation on visual studio 2019](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/232846/where-to-place-the-essential-wstp-files-in-visual-studio-2019)

> For Visual Studio 2019: The wstp.h file MUST be placed in
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include The wstp64i4.lib file
> ```
>
> The wstp64i4.lib file should be placed in should be placed in
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\lib\Hostx64\x64 The
> ```
>
> wsprep.exe file should be placed in
>
> ```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\Hostx64\x64
> ```

Comment: Please include the solution inline, in the body of your answer.